# python mysql connectivity via ssh

Tags: python, mysql, selenium, ssh

I connect to my db manually using these steps:

```
1>load a putty session with ip 1.1.1.1 and port 1111  
2>login as: login1  
3>login1@1.1.1.1's password: pwd1  
4>[login1@G ~]$ ssh login1@2.2.2.2  
5>[login1@l ~]$ MySQL -h 3.3.3.3 -u login2 -p'pwd2' -D mydb
```

Now I can can query anything successfully like select * from my_table.

I have a python selenium webdriver code from where I want to read my db. I am not able to achieve it because of ssh tunnelling and 3 IP's involved.

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
         ('host', 1111),
         ssh_password="pwd1
         ssh_username="login1",
         remote_bind_address=('2.2.2.2', 1111)) as server:

    con = None
    con = MySQLdb.connect(user='login2',passwd='pwd2',db='mydb',host=3.3.3.3,port=3306)
    cur = con.cursor()
```

I am getting this error:

### BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not resolve IP address for %s, aborting!

Answer (score 1):

When instantiating `SSHTunnelForwarder`:

The param `host` is your remote ssh `2.2.2.2`.
Argument for `remote_bind_address` will be for the tunnel, the port is the one you want to tunnel, so your mysql port. `('3.3.3.3', 3306)`

Then when connecting to mysql, you want it to pass though the tunnel to access the mysql instance. The tunnel port is `server.local_bind_port`.

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('2.2.2.2', 1111),
    ssh_password="pwd1"
    ssh_username="login1",
    remote_bind_address=('3.3.3.3', 3306)) as server:

    con = MySQLdb.connect(
        user='login2',passwd='pwd2',
        db='mydb',host=1.1.1.1,
        port=server.local_bind_port)
```

Comment: 2015-10-08 19:59:26,322 | WARNING | Could not read SSH configuration file: ~/.ssh/config
2015-10-08 19:59:26,375 | INFO    | Connecting to gateway: 2.2.2.2:1111 as user "login1".
2015-10-08 19:59:47,375 | ERROR   | Could not connect to gateway: 2.2.2.2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\API.py", line 23, in <module>
    remote_bind_address=('3.3.3.3', 3306)) as server:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py", line 626, in __init__
    raise BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError(msg)
BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not connect to gateway: 2.2.2.2

Comment: `Could not read SSH configuration file: ~/.ssh/config`. 
probably a permission issue.

Comment: Does it means I should have one of the ip in my host file?

Comment: Sadly `sshtunel` mute the original error. Could you transform [this line](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L634) in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py` into `except paramiko.SSHException as err: msg = 'Could not connect to gateway: {0}\n{1}'.format(ssh_host, err)`

Comment: Unable to connect to 2.2.2.2: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Any idea about this error. I read somewhere to add ip in host file, but which ip from 3 ip listed.

Comment: If you can connect manually, I doubt messing with host file will do something.

Comment: any other suggestion which I should try. I can connect very smoothly manually.

Comment: Put `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)` at the beginning of your code to output debug information including sshtunel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91766/discussion-between-cyrbil-and-user3388005).